# prove that a function is uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus

prove that f(x)=
\begin{cases}
{1-cos(x)\over x^2}, & \text{if $x\neq0$} \\
{1\over 2}, & \text{if $x=0$} \\
\end{cases} 
is uniformly continuous in $\mathbb R$ with the definition of uniformly continuous function please I need your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the fact that a function with bounded derivative in $\mathbb R$ is uniformly-continuous in $\mathbb R$ . Calculate the derivative ( need to be a bit careful near zero), and show that the derivative is bounded.

Comment: I can´t use derivates in this exercise just the definition of uniformly continuous function

Comment: O.K; then try to show that for any $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta >0$, so that $|f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon $ whenever $|x-y|< \delta$.

Comment: I am trying to do that but I can´t find a way to simplify the expression

Comment: How about this: notice that your function is bounded above by $1/x^2$ , and below by $0$. If you're away from $0$, each of these functions is uniformly continuous. Now you just need to work near $0$ to see what happens there.

Comment: but it doesn´t matter that in $({\pi\over 2},{3\pi\over 2})$ the funtion f(x) is above ${1\over x^2}$?

Comment: Yes; this interval takes special attention; the idea works outside of a neighborhood of $0$. Let me think of an idea for this.

Comment: Glad to help, David. Notice this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%281-cosx%29%2Fx%5E2+

Comment: This plot gives you an idea of what the function looks like near zero. Also, if you know how to find the derivative, you can use the derivative to find how fast the function grows near zero and find values of $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ that work for the function near zero.